# Layout esticado JsPdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf

comecei a usar o JSPdf, e enquanto minha pagina tem pouco conteudo, tudo ocorre tranquilo, mas se ela for grande, o layout distorce, alguem sabe por que?

Segue a imagem e o codigo a baixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
let doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
let options = {
     format: 'PNG',
     pagesplit: true
}

doc.addHTML($('#draft')[0], 0, 0, options, function(){
     doc.output('dataurlnewwindow')
})
```

Atualização: Descobri que é por causa do `pagesplit: true`, se eu declarar como `false`, funciona certo, porem, não cria novas paginas se o conteúdo for grande. Alguem sabe como solucionar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que é por causa do `pagesplit: true`, se eu declarar como false